# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Version 11 with VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a winform app that scrapes .doc files to glean info from them.  It's using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word V14 and works fine on my windows 7 machine with Office 2010.  Now I need to make this app work on XP with Office 2003.  So i was going to add a reference to v11 of the dll but could not find it.  I downloaded the PIA installer from here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897646 but the install just disappears a second into the install.

How do I add a reference to V11 of the interop libraries without having office 2003 installed?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You don't need PIAs anymore with the VS2010 Embed Interop Types feature.  Are you sure your app doesn't work on that machine?

Comment: The app works fine on win7/office 2010 but doesn't on xp/office 2003.  With 2003 it doesn't launch word (i use the interop.word library and keep the word application visible so you can see it launch, but with 2003 it doesn't launch) no exception is thrown, but it doesn't read the .doc file

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thank you, you were correct.  I just needed to change the Embed Interop Types property on the assemblies to True.  Found an article on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx.  Now its working on win7/office2010 and xp/office2003.  Thanks for pointing me down the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change the Embed Interop Types property on the assemblies to True. Found an article on it here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx. Now its working on win7/office2010 and xp/office2003. Thanks for pointing me down the correct path Hans!